# wordpress stop redirect to wp-login.php after incorrect/empty login

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication

I have a short code function that renders a login form for affiliate login (which is separate from a normal user login for which I have a "my-account" page) that can redirect to a url or the current page.

```
function affiliates_login_redirect( $atts, $content = null ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'redirect_url' => '' ), $atts ) );
        $form = '';
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
            if ( empty( $redirect_url ) ) {
                $redirect_url = get_permalink();
            }
            $form = wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => false, 'redirect' => $redirect_url ) );
        }
        return $form;
    }
```

It works fine but, if there is an invalid entry in the login form or the fields are kept empty, it redirects to wp-login.php

I have checked options which include http://www.markomedia.com.au/wordpress-login-widget-redirect-prevention/
but I am unsure how to use that solution along with my shortcode function. I can add it to functions.php but the concern is that I also have woocommerce enabled, which produces a separate login form under my-account page that is used for normal user login.

Can somebody please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

in `get_permalink();`
 pass id of the page on which you want to redirect as 
`<?php echo get_page_link(40); ?>`

try this (Provide the id of your page)

```
function affiliates_login_redirect( $atts, $content = null ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'redirect_url' => '' ), $atts ) );
        $form = '';
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
            if ( empty( $redirect_url ) ) {
                $redirect_url = echo get_page_link(40);
            }
            $form = wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => false, 'redirect' => $redirect_url ) );
        }
        return $form;
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, it is not working,when I add the page id , i am unable to login to the backend and my site has also unavailable

Answer (score 0):

## Add this in function.php Hope this will help you.

```
            function custom_authenticate( $user, $username, $password ) {
             
                if ( is_wp_error( $user ) && isset( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ] ) && !strpos( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ], 'wp-admin' ) && !strpos( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ], 'wp-login.php' ) ) {
                  $referrer = $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ];
                  foreach ( $user->errors as $key => $error ) {
                     if ( in_array( $key, array( 'empty_password', 'empty_username') ) ) {
                        unset( $user->errors[ $key ] );
                        $user->errors[ 'custom_'.$key ] = $error;
                        wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );
                     }
                  }
                }
             
                return $user;
            }
            add_filter('authenticate','custom_authenticate', 31, 3);
```